# Change sub query to join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

all I have used subquery[Below] to identify the percentage. But I need a query without subquery. Can anyone please help me, how to use joins to calculate the percentage?

**Query used**

```
SELECT 'Dropping_Percentage', 
       ( Cast(dropped_count AS DECIMAL(16, 9)) / Cast(new_count AS DECIMAL(16, 9 
                                                                   )) ) * 
       100 
FROM   (SELECT count AS New_count, 
               '1'   a 
        FROM   new_count)a, 
       (SELECT Count(*) Dropped_count, 
               '1'      b 
        FROM   pfo_bhi_new N 
               RIGHT JOIN pfo_bhi_old o 
                       ON o.id_membid_claimid_c = N.id_membid_claimid_c 
        WHERE  N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL)c 
WHERE  a.a = c.b
```

Comment: could you please add some sample data in your question

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Does your current query work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

"I need a query without subquery."

**Answer:**

```
SELECT Count(*) All_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end) as Dropped_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end) * 1.0 / Count(*) as Dropping_Percentage
FROM pfo_bhi_new N 
RIGHT JOIN pfo_bhi_old o ON o.id_membid_claimid_c = N.id_membid_claimid_c
```

**Explanation:**

Reviewing the main query with assumptions about the content:

```
SELECT Count(*) Dropped_count, '1' b 
FROM pfo_bhi_new N 
RIGHT JOIN pfo_bhi_old o ON o.id_membid_claimid_c = N.id_membid_claimid_c 
WHERE N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL
```

should give you the number of records in pfo_bhi_old that do not appear in pfo_bhi_new.  Assumption here is that you need to do the total based on the existing right join.  All the matching and non matching records.

Therefore It's possible to count all the existing records by removing the where clause, 
**COUNT(*)** would give you that total.

Next you want to count the ones where there's no match which will give you the "Dropping count" the value you had before with the where clause, that is where ones where the id_membid_claimid_c was null that is **SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end)**.  Said differently it will add 1 to the sum only when the id_membid_claimid_c field is null, otherwise it will add zero (0).

I've multiplied the numerator by 1.0 to force SQL Server to use decimal values and make the query easier to read.

Here's what it should look like if you needed to use decimals(16,9) as the result.

```
SELECT Count(*) All_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end) as Dropped_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end) * 1.0 / Count(*) as Dropping_Percentage

     , CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN N.id_membid_claimid_c IS NULL THEN 1 else 0 end) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) / CAST(Count(*) AS DECIMAL(16,9)) as Dropping_Pct_16_9

FROM pfo_bhi_new N 
RIGHT JOIN pfo_bhi_old o ON o.id_membid_claimid_c = N.id_membid_claimid_c
```